# Mule API to move from HTTP to HTTPs

Tags: java, http, https, mule

Earlier we have HTTP api of Mule service. As we are moving to ssl . We need our api calls to https . So need to know the ways to the same in less time duration and without much efforts .

Comment: This is asked in the initial days of Mule API

Answer (score 1):

We have ways to implement them. I would suggest using shared resources [domains](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/shared-resources#creating-a-new-domain).

> **Steps include:**

1. Create a domain project with HTTPS shared resource in your workspace.
2. associate all of your APIs to that domain. For this, you need to update mule-project.xml and select domain.
3. Go to HTTP connector in each of your API and simply select the **connector configuration** from drop down. (If the domain project is created correctly, the HTTP shared resource from domain should come in this drop down!)

In this way, you can migrate all your APIs to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

```
This below code will make mule api calls to HTTPs 

<http:listener-config name="httpListenerConfig" host="0.0.0.0" port="${http.port}" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" protocol="HTTPS">
        <tls:context>
            <tls:key-store type="jks" path="${keyname}" keyPassword="${keypassword}" password="${keypassword}"/>
        </tls:context>
    </http:listener-config>

where key needs to be put in resources folder and password to properties file.
```

Comment: <http:listener-config name="httpListenerConfig" host="0.0.0.0" port="${http.port}" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" protocol="HTTPS">
        <tls:context>
            <tls:key-store type="jks" path="${keyname}" keyPassword="${keypassword}" password="${keypassword}"/>
        </tls:context>
    </http:listener-config>